# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable facing this error while working with pywhatkit in python

Tags: python-3.x

I was creating a personal assistant for which I was automating whatsapp chat using pywhatkit module in python suddenly got this error could not fix after working lot of hours on this. Someone please help.
What can I do to fix this problem?

The code:

```
 elif 'send a message' in query:
        speak("tell me the phone number")
        phone = str(takecommand())
        speak("tell me the message")
        message = str(takecommand())
        speak("when should i send message")
        speak("\ntime in hours")
        time_hour = int(takecommand())
        speak("time in minutes")
        time_min = int(takecommand())
        speak("how much should I wait before sending message")
        wait_time = int(takecommand())
        kit.sendwhatmsg(f"+91{phone}", message , time_hour(), time_min(), wait_time())
        speak("Ok sir! sending message")
```

Error I receievd (After runing program):

```
User said: send a message


: tell me the phone number

Listening...

recognizing

User said: xxxx xxx xxx


: tell me the message

Listening...

recognizing

User said: testing


: when should i send message
   
: 
time in hours

Listening...

recognizing

User said: 21


: time in minutes

Listening...

recognizing

User said: 24


: how much should I wait before sending message

Listening...

recognizing

User said: 20

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\AI Chat Bot\Project JARVIS\jarvis.py", line 122, in <module>
    kit.sendwhatmsg(f"+91{phone}", message , time_hour(), time_min(), wait_time())
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: `time_hour = int(...)` then later `time_hour()` what do you expect this to do? you are setting a variable to an integer then calling it like a function.

Comment: Ya, you are trying to invoke a function when in actuality the variable is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to invoke a variable as if it were a function when it is an integer.

Change this line...

```py
kit.sendwhatmsg(f"+91{phone}", message , time_hour(), time_min(), wait_time())
```

To this...

```py
kit.sendwhatmsg(f"+91{phone}", message , time_hour, time_min, wait_time)
```